# InvocationTargetException when generating cloud endpoint class

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-endpoints

When I click to generate cloud endpoint client library, I receive the following on the error log.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.MissingParameterNameException: tuberservice.com.rune.tuber.server.TuberServiceImpl.TuberServiceImpl.getInitParameter parameter (type class java.lang.String): Missing parameter name. Parameter type (class java.lang.String) is not an entity type and thus should be annotated with @Named.
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:292)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.MissingParameterNameException: tuberservice.com.rune.tuber.server.TuberServiceImpl.TuberServiceImpl.getInitParameter parameter (type class java.lang.String): Missing parameter name. Parameter type (class java.lang.String) is not an entity type and thus should be annotated with @Named.
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validateApiParameter(ApiConfigValidator.java:271)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validateParameter(ApiConfigValidator.java:229)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validateMethod(ApiConfigValidator.java:169)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validateMethods(ApiConfigValidator.java:130)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validate(ApiConfigValidator.java:93)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validate(ApiConfigValidator.java:63)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.writeConfig(JsonConfigWriter.java:102)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.generateConfig(AnnotationApiConfigGenerator.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:288)
    ... 3 more
```

Here is my service implementation

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Api(name = "tuberservice")
public class TuberServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        TuberService {

    @Override
    @ApiMethod(name = "addClient")
    public String addClientService(TuberClient t) {
        if (t != null){
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
            pm.makePersistent(t);
            pm.close();
            return t.toString();
        }
        return "Invalid client";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @ApiMethod(name = "listClients")
    public TuberClient[] listAllClientsService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //select from TuberClient
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query q = pm.newQuery(TuberClient.class);
        List<TuberClient> list = (List<TuberClient>) q.execute();
        ArrayList<TuberClient> returnList = new ArrayList<TuberClient>();
        for (TuberClient t : list){
            returnList.add(t);
        }//end for
        pm.close();
        return (TuberClient[])returnList.toArray(new TuberClient[0]);
    }

}
```

I've been looking for a solution to the problem for hours now. I tried reverting to appengine1.8.8 and it didnt work, I tried rebuilding, cleaning, etc, didnt and I even tried deploying to appengine and that didn't work.

I literally don't know where to begin to resolve the error because i DO NOT have any strings in my server implementation to annotate so Im overall very confused.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return `String` from Cloud Endpoints methods.

This line will not compile:

```
public String addClientService(TuberClient t)
```

This is also suspicious:

```
extends RemoteServiceServlet implements TuberService
```

Check if you don't have any API methods there which returns `String`.

Please read this [guide](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities). Double check your code if it returns valid values and every required parameter has it corresponding `@Name` annotation.

> In the Endpoint methods, the return value type cannot be simple type
>   such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array
>   or a Collection. Also, list() and get() are exposed as HTTP GETs,
>   insert() is exposed as a HTTP POST, update() is exposed as a HTTP PUT,
>   and removeNote() is exposed as a HTTP DELETE.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it didnt work. I created a class called Void that was completely empty and used that as my return type and i get the EXACT same error. I don't even pass in or return a string in my server implementation. This is just frustrating.

Comment: @ChuckOnwuzuruike check the updated answer. Try to remove `extends RemoteServiceServlet implements TuberService` if it works without these classes it means the problem is inside `RemoteServiceServlet` or `TuberService`

Comment: Wait, but if I remove that stuff won't my appengine rpc server stop working?

Comment: @ChuckOnwuzuruike I don't know what you're using in your app but Cloud Endpoints classes don't need to extend any services or implement interfaces, those are plain classes with `@Api` annotation. Be careful what you extend or implement because all public methods are exported as endpoint methods (You don't need to annotate it as `@ApiMethod`)

Comment: All my app does is ask a user for their name and it just saves it do a data store. I do this using app engine. I figured I would try and hit the TuberService from an android device so i figured i'd use the endpoints thing. So i guess my question is, how does appengine talk to my backend server if I remove the "extends RemoteServices...." stuff?

Comment: By using the generated client library by Google Cloud Endpoints. Seems you're doing it wrong. Do not extend any class, just find a beginner tutorial for Cloud Endpoints and start from scratch.